# Set of matrices related to simultaneous diagonalization?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I want to understand the properties of the following set of matrices. Given a matrix $R \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times q}$, the set is:

$\qquad \{Q : Q^T \operatorname{diag}(d) Q = R^T \operatorname{diag}(d) R, \quad \forall d \ge 0\}$.

Obviously the equality holds even when we multiply rows of $R$ by $-1$, but are there other transformations that preserve equality? And does this set of matrices have any connection to the concept of simultaneous diagonalization?

Comment: Is $\operatorname diag (d) = dI$, the matrix with $d$ on the diagonal and $0$ everywhere else? If yes, your property reduces to $Q^TQ = R^TR$ .

Comment: No, I just mean that the matrix is diagonal with diagonal elements $d_{ii} \ge 0, \forall i$.